# Detect closed shutter

Tags: remote-control

I want to controll some ambient lights in my living room.

Therefore, I got some 433mhz outlets which can be turned on or off with an remote, a 433mhz transmitter and receiver on the arduino.

The arduino receives the remotes signals and knows which lamp has which state and will turn any lamp off at specific times.

Now I want to turn on the lights automatically when I close the shutter, but I have no idea how I could do this.

A light sensor behind the window won't do the job. I don't want to turn on the lights when it get's dark, but when the shuhtter get's closed.

Edit:
What came to my mind first was an light sensor inside the window, facing outside, and a IR LED. I'd attach some tinfoil to the inside of the shutter to return the IR light, which the sensor will notice. But maybe the're are some simpler solutions? Also, the tinfoil would fall off quickly...

Comment: Is there some cord or something you could attach a magnet to, which you could detect, being in the closed position?

Comment: Not without getting ugly =(

Comment: What is this mythical shutter? How does it operate? What is it made of? Does it slide like a blind, or close like a door? Roll? Solid? Made of pressed geranium leaves? Please, we need some actual information.

Comment: It's a roller shutter. It rolls up in a box inside the wall, above the window. Aside the window there is a cord which i pull to let the shutter down.

Comment: I'd use a magnet in place of the tinfoil and a (latching) hall-effect-sensor/reed-switch instead of the photo-reflector you were planning to use.

Comment: Nice idea. I could simply drill a little hole in the lowest shutter-bar and glue in an magnet. Simple. But these sensors are surprisingly expensive, what are they made of, pure gold? I mean, IR sensors cost about 10-20% of that price o.O

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the wrong things.  Think household security - reed switch / magnet pairs for doors. Very cheap.

Comment: To avoid doing anything to the shutter itself you could use an ultrasonic sensor. These also have a benefit of working over a longer range than door/window magnet-and-reed-switch setups, thus the shutter doesn't need to close all the way to activate the lights. You can set the threshold in code.

Comment: I have a cat which walks on the windows sill now and then. Ultrasonic is usually a good idea, but doesn't fit the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a normally open read switch (should cost >$0.1) and a magnet on the shutter (again should cost >$0.1).  There are formulas to work out the distance that the reed switch will operate at, and it depends on the magnet, but the common ones are about 40mm.
(If you can wait 2 weeks for delivery you can get the parts off AliExpress.com)